# 2019 Macbook Air - Ubuntu Wifi Drivers not working

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers, macos

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 and have the keyboard/trackpad working. However the wireless card is not showing up in the settings. I've tried installing the firmware-b43-installer with no success. It looks like it can see the wireless card but it is not active. modprobe wl doesn't seem to do anything.

```
  Model: "Broadcom Network controller"
    Driver Status: hci_bcm4377 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe hci_bcm4377"
    Driver Status: wl is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe wl"
  Model: "Broadcom BCM4377b Wireless Network Adapter"
    Driver Status: brcmfmac is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe brcmfmac"
    Driver Status: wl is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe wl"

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
73:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4377b Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4488] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4377b Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0870]
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac, wl
73:00.1 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BRCM4377 Bluetooth Controller [14e4:5fa0] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:0870]
    Kernel modules: hci_bcm4377, wl
74:00.0 Mass storage controller [0180]: Apple Inc. ANS2 NVMe Controller [106b:2005] (rev 01)
```

Comment: If you installed the correct driver now you may need to deal with Secure Boot. Either disable it or, preferably, sign the drivers with MOKutil.